# How can I extend my existing Custom User Model created with AbstractBaseUser to have multiple user types like customer, trainer and author?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I have an existing custom user model which I created based on the [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) to have **email-based** authentication.

I want to extend the model to have multiple user types like Customers, Trainers, and Authors.

I am not sure how to go forward and what is the best way to extend this?

Also, have I made the right choice going with the **AbstractBaseUser** or should I have used the **AbstractUser** Class.

Comment: share your existing models, please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman I only have the accounts model right now with the custom right now with [This is the code in my models.py with a few additional fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example).

Answer (score 1):

rename your MyUser class to MyUserBase or MyUserAbstract, then in this class

```
class MyUserBase(AbstractBaseUser):
  class Meta:
    abstract = True
  .
  .
  .
```

now you can extend it:

then recreate your MyUser class like this:

```
class MyUser(MyUserBase):
  pass
```

and the other models like this:

```
class Trainer(MyUserBase):
  ... #other properties

class Customer(MyUserBase):
  ... #other properties
```